# Interrupted plot lines when multiple branches of an ODE solution are plotted

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I am plotting the following:

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[Piecewise[{{Abs[x]*Sqrt[Log[x^2] + 2 i], 
      x < -Exp[-i]}, {Abs[x]*Sqrt[Log[x^2] + 2 i], x > Exp[-i]}}, 
    None], {i, -2, 3, 1}]], {x, -3, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1}}]
```

What I am getting is this:
[image]

The two lines closest to the `y` axis are interrupted. Why? And why the plot line starts further and further away from zero as one increases the `i`? The one sided limits are clear and the function tends to zero... Now, if I only print a single branch there are no interruptions.

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[Piecewise[{{Abs[x]*Sqrt[Log[x^2] + 2 i], 
      x < -Exp[-i]}, {Abs[x]*Sqrt[Log[x^2] + 2 i], x > Exp[-i]}}, 
    None], {i, 1, 1, 1}]], {x, -3, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

**Note**, my piecewise definition might be wrong, I was trying to tell mathematica that for $|x|<e^{-i}$ the function is not defined, if I don't include the `None` portion, Mathematica keeps connecting the points $-e^{-i}$ and $e^{-i}$ with a line at $y=0$ which is wrong and this was the only way that I was able to find to prevent this behaviour.

Comment: There are no gaps in version 13.2 Windows 10

Comment: `Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[Piecewise[{{Abs[x]*Sqrt[Log[x^2] + 2 i], 
      x < -Exp[-i]}, {Abs[x]*Sqrt[Log[x^2] + 2 i], x > Exp[-i]}}, 
    None], {i, -2, 3, 1}]], {x, -9, 9}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-9, 9}, {0, 10}}, ScalingFunctions -> {None, None}]`

Comment: @Syed Still gaps, I am on `13.1` Linux.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EhxQ.png is what I see on v12.2.0 on Win7-x64.

Comment: I can confirm the same behaviour on macos the same version.

Comment: @Syed In your case the gaps in the middle are gone but the start of the lines also seems to keep attaining the distance from the x axis with `i` becoming smaller (negative).

Comment: Add the option `Exclusions -> None`. The gaps (probably) come from `Piecewise`, but I don't have time to confirm right now.

Answer (score 1):

This shows that the gaps come from discontinuities in one function being applied to other functions in the `Plot`.  You can use `Exclusions -> None` to remove them, or plot each function individually.

```
gl = Table[
     Piecewise[{{Abs[x]*Sqrt[Log[x^2] + 2 i], 
        x < -Exp[-i]}, {Abs[x]*Sqrt[Log[x^2] + 2 i], x > Exp[-i]}}, 
      None], {i, -2, 3, 1}] // 
    Map[SolveValues[FunctionDiscontinuities[#, x], x] &] // N // 
  Apply@Union
(*
{-7.38906, -2.71828, -1., -0.367879, -0.135335, -0.0497871, \
0.0497871, 0.135335, 0.367879, 1., 2.71828, 7.38906}
*)

Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[Piecewise[{{Abs[x]*Sqrt[Log[x^2] + 2 i], 
      x < -Exp[-i]}, {Abs[x]*Sqrt[Log[x^2] + 2 i], x > Exp[-i]}}, 
    None], {i, -2, 3, 1}]], {x, -3, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1}}, 
 GridLines -> {gl, None}(*,Exclusions->None*)]
```

[image]